# MySQL Forward Engineer - SQL giving error 121

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm currently trying to create my database using the *Forward Engineer* wizard of MySQL Workbench but I get this error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'microweb.users' (errno: 121)


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `microweb`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `role_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `salt` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `middle_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `address_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `registration_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `banned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `registration_id_UNIQUE` (`registration_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_role`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_id` )
    REFERENCES `microweb`.`roles` (`role_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_registration`
    FOREIGN KEY (`registration_id` )
    REFERENCES `microweb`.`registrations` (`registration_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed
```

The complete scripts contains a lot of foreign keys and 21 tables. The problem is that there's only 2 in phpMyAdmin after the execution when Workbench says there's 10 successful.

If someone need the complete model, just tell me.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench is this? Are you using the latest one?

Comment: @MikeLischke Yes, I installed it 4 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 121 indicates there are duplicate key names. You must make sure yourself that all your FK names are unique accross the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying it without the constraints first, then add the constraints using `ALTER TABLE`.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `microweb`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `role_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `salt` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `middle_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `address_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `registration_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `banned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `registration_id_UNIQUE` (`registration_id` ASC)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `microweb`.`users`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_role`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_id` )
    REFERENCES `microweb`.`roles` (`role_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `microweb`.`users`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_registration`
    FOREIGN KEY (`registration_id` )
    REFERENCES `microweb`.`registrations` (`registration_id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this by default when using the *Forward Engineer* wizard of Workbench?

Comment: Hmm, is there a PHP script or a regex I can use to automatically create the "ALTER TABLE" query for the foreign keys? Because 21 tables, it's gonna be long!

Comment: Don't know of one; I write DDL syntax by hand without an IDE